# Trouble with simple acronym program python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to make an acronym program where the user can enter 1 word per line and after entering a blank space the program will output the word created by the first letter of each word. It is printing a whitespace after the output which I don't want. Any Ideas on how to remove that? More information below:

E.g

```
User input:
Word: Hello
Word: World

Desired output:
Hello World <-- whitespace here that I don't want
-- HW

My Current Code that works:

words = []
word = input('Word: ')
while word:
  words.append(word)
  word = input('Word: ') #Word input

for word in words:

   print(word, end=" ") #displays all words on one line 

  # Printing a white space ^

# Wanting to print this code on a new line 
first_letters = ''.join([word[0] for word in words])
new=first_letters.upper()
print("\n-- " + new)
```

Comment: I have code that produces the output I want but it prints a whitespace after printing the words that the user enters. Any Ideas on how to remove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does everything you want

```
words = []
word = input('Word: ')
while word:
  words.append(word)
  word = input('Word: ') #Word input


print(' '.join(words))


first_letters = ''.join([word[0] for word in words])
new=first_letters.upper()
print("-- " + new)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Combining what you had with `num` and `print`:

```
for word in words:
    print(word[:1], end="")  # Display all first letters without spaces.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply this?

```
words = ['Hello','World']
print(' '.join(w for w in words))
print('-- '+''.join(w[0] for w in words))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given array of strings `words`. There are several approaches to get first letters of the words. Few of them are below.

### First approach

```py
first_letters = ''
for word in words:
  first_letters += word[0]
print(first_letters)
```

### Second approach

```py
first_letters = ''.join([word[0] for word in words])
print(first_letters)
```